# C++ - invalid conversion

Tags: c++, pointers, integer

The code shows an invalid conversion from int to *int how do I fix the problem ... the full detail of error is given below :

**Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isSafe(int** arr[], int x, int y, int n)
{
    if (x > n && y > n && arr[x][y] == 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool ratInmaze(int** arr[], int x, int y, int n, int** solArr[])
{
    if (x == n - 1 && y == n - 1)
    {
        solArr[x][y] = 1;
        return false;
    }

    if (isSafe(arr, x, y, n))
    {
        solArr[x][y] = 1;

        if (ratInmaze(arr, x + 1, y, n, solArr))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (ratInmaze(arr, x, y + 1, n, solArr))
        {
            return true;
        }
        solArr[x][y] = 0;
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int **arr = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = new int[n];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }

    int **solArr = new int *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        solArr[i] = new int[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            solArr[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    if (ratInmaze(arr,0,0,n,solArr))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            cout<<solArr[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
        
    }
    
}
```

**AND THE COMPILER SAYS**:
[Error] invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int**' [-fpermissive] [Error] invalid conversion from 'int**' to 'int' [-fpermissive] What does it mean? Thanks

Comment: Look at your functions' (first) argument types (`int** x[]`) and then at your `arr` type in `main` (`int** arr;`). See any difference?

Comment: There are multiple improper pointer sequences in this code.  `int** arr[]` as an argument is synonymous to `int ***arr`. Therefore `arr[x][y] == 1` is nonsense; you're comparing an `int*` (from `arr[x][y]`) to an `int` (1). The same problem appears in multiple locations in this code. Ex: `solArr[x][y] = 1;` is equally nonsense, for similar reasons. In both cases one level of indirection needs to be *removed* from the function parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing c-arrays to functions is an oddity inherited from C. When you write

```
void foo(T a[]);
```

Then this is actually shorthand notation for

```
void foo(T* a);
```

Because arrays cannot be passed by value. They decay to a pointer to their first element when passed to functions. Hence,

```
bool ratInmaze(int** arr[], int x, int y, int n, int** solArr[]);
```

is actually

```
bool ratInmaze(int*** arr, int x, int y, int n, int*** solArr);
```

but you try to call it with `sol` and `arr` which both are `int**`. And there are more errors, most related to that confusion. I suggest you to use `std::vector` for dynamically sized arrays and `std::array` for statically sized arrays to stay away from such pointer madness. If you really want to manage the arrays manually you should still wrap them inside a class that can be passed to functions by value.